# htlatex clean working environment

Tags: pdftex, htlatex

When I create a PDF of my `main.tex` file, I do it like:

```
pdflatex -output-directory=build main.tex
```

This way the PDF file and all the other (suff) files generated during the process goes in the `build` folder.

I just learned how to create HTML from `main.tex`, doing:

```
htlatex main.tex
```

It generates a `main.html` file and a lot of other (stuff) files.

Is there an option to make it a little cleanly? Perhaps build in a dedicated folder?

Comment: Symbolic links are one way to do this. Make a `convert` directory which contains symlinks to the source files and directories you need to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `-output-directory` to `htlatex` as well:

```
htlatex filename xhtml "" "" " -output-directory=build"
```

The problem with this approach is that `tex4ht` is searching for the generated `dvi` file in the current directory, so it fails:

```
Output written on build/filename.dvi (1 page, 9632 bytes).
Transcript written on build/filename.log.
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht -f/filename 
  -i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ 
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `filename.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `filename.dvi'
```

The solution is to use `make4ht`, which is much more powerful way to call `tex4ht` than `htlatex`.

With `make4ht`, you can use a build file to modify the compilation parameters and to move files to a correct destination. Save the following code as `mybuild.mk4`:

```
local outdir = "build"
local newinput = outdir .."/" ..settings.input
settings.latex_par= "-output-directory=".. outdir 
settings.input = newinput

Make:match(".css$", "mv ${filename} ".. outdir .."/${filename}")
Make:match(".tmp$", "rm ${filename}")
```

The build file is Lua script, output directory name is saved in `outdir` variable, we then modify default settings to use the `outdir`, `settings.latex_par` contains parameters for LaTeX, `settings.input` is the location of the `dvi` file. `Make:match` is used to fix location of some files generated by `tex4ht`, which don't follow the `-output-directory` option. The first one moves the `css` file to the output dir, because it is written by `tex4ht` to the current dir. If you use Windows, replace `mv` with `move`. The second deletes `filename.tmp` file. Again, if you use Windows, replace `rm` with `del`.

You can compile the document using

```
make4ht -e mybuild.mk4 filename
```

And the output structure is following:

```
$ ls -R1
.:
build
filename.tex
mybuild.mk4

./build:
filename.aux
filename.css
filename.dvi
filename.html
filename.idv
filename.lg
filename.log
filename.tmp
filename.xref
filename.4ct
filename.4tc
```