# Ideal directory structure for make4ht, clean build

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

It's being suggested [make4ht](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/support/make4ht/make4ht-doc.pdf) can replace the functionalities provided by [htlatex](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial) (i.e. [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346295/htlatex-clean-working-environment?noredirect=1#comment849775_346295)) to generate HTML from LATEX documents. I'm interested on it.

Particularly, I would like to put in place an ideal directory structure in order to facilitate generation of both PDF and HTML. Until now I have something like:

```
├── html
├── pdf
│   ├── main.aux
│   ├── main.bcf
│   ├── main.log
│   ├── main.out
│   ├── main.pdf
│   ├── main.run.xml
│   └── main.toc
└── tex
    ├── main.sty
    ├── main.tex
    ├── pdflatex.sh
    └── sub.tex
```

It kind of solve my needs for the PDF case. I already added an `html` folder there, where I'm planning to work with the `make4ht`.

Question: How should I proceed in order to generate the `.html` file in the `html folder` using `make4ht`? Should I use a build file (how it would look like)?

Following are the contents of my project files:

To trigger the PDF generation I call `pdflatex.sh` (from inside `tex` folder):

pdflatex.sh

```
cd ..
mkdir -p pdf
pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=pdf tex/main.tex
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tex/main}

\begin{document}

\title{\truncate[]{15cm}{\lipsum[8]}}
\author{\truncate[]{5cm}{\lipsum[1]}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
% \thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
% \clearpage

\subimport{tex/}{sub.tex}

\blindtext
% \Blindtext
% \Blindtext[4][3]
% \blinddocument
% \Blinddocument
% \blindtext[5]
% \blindlist{itemize}[5]
% \blindenumerate[10]
% \blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

main.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{main}

%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none,sortlocale=pt-BR]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tex/relatorio.bib}
% \usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}
% \usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % para relatórios em português
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % para acentuação direta
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage{tabularx} % extra features for tabular environment
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage[margin=0.8in,letterpaper]{geometry} % decreases margins
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} % adds hyper links inside the generated pdf file
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
% \usepackage{ulem} % do no use, linebreaks on references stop working
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{appendix}

% \usepackage[strings]{underscore}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakwords]{truncate}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,     % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue         
}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\addto\captionsbrazil{%
   \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apêndice}%
   \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apêndice}%
}
\newcommand{\cubesat}{\textit{cubesat}}
\newcommand{\frames}{\textit{frames}}
\newcommand{\beacon}{\textit{beacon}}
```

sub.tex

```
\begin{abstract}

\blindtext
% \Blindtext
% \Blindtext[4][3]
% \blinddocument
% \Blinddocument
% \blindtext[5]
% \blindlist{itemize}[5]
% \blindenumerate[10]
% \blindmathpaper

\end{abstract}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can copy the generated files to different directory using `make4ht` with `--output-dir` (or `-d`) option, so you can try that:

```
make4ht -d html tex/main.tex
```

It will left your temporary files in the current dir however. You can remove them using a build file:

```lua
local function move_file(filename, args)
  local outdir = args.outdir 
  -- copy files only when --output-directory option has been used
  if outdir ~= "" then 
    local newfile = table.concat({outdir, filename}, "/")   
    print("moving the file: ".. filename .. " to directory: " .. outdir)
    os.execute("mv ".. filename .. " " .. newfile)
  end
  return false
end

Make:match("html$", function(filename, args)
  return move_file(filename, args)
end)

Make:match("css$", function(filename, args)
  return move_file(filename, args)
end)


Make:match("tmp$", function(filename, args)
  for _,ext in ipairs {"aux", "xref", "tmp", "4tc", "4ct", "idv", "lg","dvi", "log"} do
    local newfile = filename:gsub("tmp$", ext)
    print("Removing: ", newfile)
    -- you can  move the aux files to the outdir using
    move_file(newfile, args)
    -- or, alternatively, just delete it
    -- os.remove(newfile)
  end
  return false
end)
```

This will match the `.tmp` file, take it's name as the basename and move all files with extensions listed in the argument of `ipairs` function to the output directory. Alternatively, you can also delete them instead if you uncomment the `os.remove` line.

We also match `html` and `css` files. By default, they are copied to the output directory, this version will move them here instead.

One final remark: you use some macros in your `\title` command. I guess that you don't use this particular command in your real document, because it causes a compilation error.

[image]

Comment: I like the answer, @michal.h21. But, is there a way to make TeXstudio automatically delete the temp files?

Comment: @lfba I don't know much about TeXstudio, but I think it should be possible to add a new compilation command that uses `make4ht`. The build file can be saved in some common place and required using the `-e` option for any document.

Comment: Thanks again, @michal.h21. I'll try to do that.

Comment: @lfba: You can use `latexmk -C` in `Windows` (C should be caps and delete include PDF, PS and DVI, If you want PDF, PS just use -c) and `make4ht -m clean filename` without `.ext`.