# How do change the output directory of `htlatex`

Tags: html, htlatex, folders, build-system, make4ht

Every time I execute the `htlatex` command in TeXsudio (`htlatex %.tex`) I get a lot of files in my main folder. I would prefer that the target files (`html`, `css`, `png`, etc.) to a folder called `html` and all temporary files go to another folder called `htmltemp` (or simply delete them after compiling the target files). Both have to be subfolders of the main one. How should I execute `htlatex` or a similar code in order to get this outcome?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: do you want to move the generated images, HTML and CSS files, or the temporary files? the first option is possible using `make4ht -d htlatex filename.tex` (not using `htlatex`, which is obsolete).

Comment: Thanks, @michal.h21. Now that I have tested you proposal, I think I want to move the `html` and `css` to a one folder, and the temporary files to another.

Comment: I think this should do what you want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346413/2891